# SELECT Query in php: Response Too Late

Tags: php, mysql

All other pages with same Database connection works fine, but this page takes 10-15 minutes to load.

It produces correct output but takes so long although this table "user" has only 2 records.

Am I missing something or making some mistake?

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","myprojectdatabase");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user ");

while( false !== ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))){
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $row['username'];
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: bizarre. what's in your `error_log`? any warnings/notices etc?

Comment: did you try restarting mysql server? this sounds like a tablelock

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below code and see if it works for you

```
   $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","myprojectdatabase");
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user");
   while( false !=($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)))
   {
     echo"<pre>";
     echo $row['username'];
   }
   $conn->close();
```

Comment: That worked!!  Thank you. Can you tell me what was the issue in previous code?

Comment: No need to check  while( false !== ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))), you can directly use while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) or you can use != insstead of !== because its a more strict comparison

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` will return `NULL` when it fretches the last row not `false` [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: You can use this also,  while( false !=($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)))